# How to get app runtime on hadoop yarn

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, monitor

Will yarn store informations about finished app including runtime on hdfs? I just want to get the app runtime through some files on the hdfs(if there did exist such file, I have checked the logs and there is no runtime informations) without using any monitoring software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ResourceManager REST](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html) to fetch the information of all the Finished applications.

```
http://resource_manager_host:port/ws/v1/cluster/apps?state=FINISHED
```

A `GET` request to the URL will return a JSON response (XML can also be obtained). The response has to be parsed for `elapsedTime` for each application to get the running time of the application.

Comment: Since I use a `shell script` to run multi apps on yarn, if I can set yarn to automatically return the app's information when the app finished? Does it means I have to use a `while loop` to frequently ask  yarn to return the finished app information if no such automatic method?

Comment: Yes, you have to manually make requests to get the state of the application.When an application is completed, yarn provides counters which contain some relevant information but not exactly the `elapsed time`.

Answer (score 0):

To look up persistent job history file, you will need to check Job History Server or Timeline Server instead of Resource Manager:

1. Job history is aggregated onto HDFS, and can be seen from job history server UI (or REST API). The history files are stored on `mapreduce.jobhistory.done-dir` on HDFS.
2. Job history can also be aggregated by timeline server (filesystem based, aka ATS 1.5) and can be seen from timeline server UI (or REST API). The history files are stored on `yarn.timeline-service.entity-group-fs-store.done-dir` on HDFS.

Comment: Since I use a `shell script` to run multi apps on yarn, if I can set yarn to automatically return the app's information when the app finished? Does it means I have to use a `while loop` to frequently ask  yarn to return the finished app information if no such automatic method?

Comment: @0_1_Life You can run `yarn application -list -appStates FINISHED` to get a list of finished yarn app IDs, at the same time, you maintain a list of app IDs that you already have the job history. Then each time, if you find a new ID that not in your list, run e.g `yarn logs -applicationId application_1484331408245_0014 > /tmp/job_0014.log` to get and save the log info. Does that help?